# Will the k-means algorithm improve the performance of data processing?

Tags: performance, dataset, k-means

I'm trying to implement the k-means algorithm to a large dataset, cuz the goal of k-means is to partition a set of data points into k clusters.
I am not sure if I will re-partition the dataset by the k-means clusters, will it be able to improve the performance of data processing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  Try this,

partition the original dataset into blocks; each block unit, called a unit block (UB), contains at least one pattern. We can locate the centroid of a unit block (CUB) by using a simple calculation. All the computed CUBs form a reduced dataset that represents the original dataset. The reduced dataset is then used to compute the final centroid of the original dataset. We only need to examine each UB on the boundary of candidate clusters to find the closest final centroid for every pattern in the UB. In this way, we can dramatically reduce the time for calculating final converged centroids.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful! But will it be able to improve the process speed like data query or computation to a large dataset?

Comment: In our experiments, this algorithm produces comparable clustering results as other k-means algorithms, but with much better performance. Try it with your dataset.